# How to solve :Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6

Tags: maven

Have been recently Trying to create a Maven Project . I get this specific errors all the time . Please can someone help in giving a step by step tutorial to solve this issue.

Comment: Please show us complete logs.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read this [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question with sufficient and specific information to describe your problem.